# Integrate puppeteer inside google cloud function listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am running google cloud functions under node 8 runtime with 2g allocated for the listener.
Listener: works without puppeteer;
Puppeteer: works when used inside a get request;

But I want puppeteer to work inside my listener which makes my already valid listener throw an error.

I've read through many docs and none integrate puppeteer inside of a listener.

Edit: i've also tried to change the return type to a valid format to no avail.

My Valid Listener

```
exports.listen = functions.firestore
    .document('/request/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        // Grab the data from the original function trigger 
        const document = await change.after.data()['data'];

        // Dummy return of what will eventually be given
        return change.after.ref.set(
            {
                results: [
                    { title: 'New Title', Country: 'Lala Land' },
                    { title: 'New Job', Country: 'Asgardia' }
                ]
            },
            { merge: true }
        );
    });
```

Valid Puppeteer Function

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express();
// Runs before every route. Launches headless Chrome.
app.all('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  // Note: --no-sandbox is required in this env.
  // Could also launch chrome and reuse the instance
  // using puppeteer.connect()
  res.locals.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  next(); // pass control to next route.
});
// Handler to take screenshots of a URL.
app.get('/screenshot', async function screenshotHandler(req, res) {
  const url = req.query.url;
  if (!url) {
    return res.status(400).send(
      'Please provide a URL. Example: ?url=https://example.com');
  }
  const browser = res.locals.browser;
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    const buffer = await page.screenshot({fullPage: true});
    res.type('image/png').send(buffer);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e.toString());
  }
  await browser.close();
});
```

Invalid Listener with puppeteer changed to minimal needs

```
exports.listen = functions.firestore
    .document('/request/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const document = change.after.data()['data'];
        async function benchmark() {

            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                args: ['--no-sandbox']
            });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('http://picocms.org/', {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
            });
            const content = await page.content();
            return content;
        }

        return change.after.ref.set(
            {
                // results: [
                //  { title: 'New Title', Country: 'Lala Land' },
                //  { title: 'New Job', Country: 'Asgardia' }
                // ]
                results: benchmark()
            },
            { merge: true }
        );
    });
```

Error Generated In Logs

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object (found in field results).
    at Object.validateUserInput (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:312:15)
    at validateDocumentData (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:622:26)
    at WriteBatch.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:242:9)
    at DocumentReference.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:337:27)
    at exports.listen.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/srv/index.js:57:27)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:114:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Comment: If anyone has their own creation of a minimal listener with puppeteer integrated feel free to drop their working snippet.

Comment: Your error message doesn't appear to have anything to do with puppeteer.  I'd say you have a problem with this line: `const document = change.after.data()['data'];`

Comment: The thing is, it works without the puppeteer code correctly, I've tested it with no errors and it gives the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should really make docs for this use but I found my own solution, I just have to conform to using puppeteer in a post or get request as you won't has access to the (request, response) params.

For anyone wanting to use this in their own way here is a minimal viable solution to build off of.

Note: I upgraded the runtime to Node 10 (beta) with 2G allocated.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = require('express')();
const { db } = require('./util/admin');

// Runs before every route. Launches headless Chrome.
app.all('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    // Note: --no-sandbox is required in this env.
    // Could also launch chrome and reuse the instance
    // using puppeteer.connect()
    res.locals.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
    next(); // pass control to next route.
});

app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    const request = {
        data: req.body.data,
        created: new Date().toISOString()
    };
    const browser = res.locals.browser;
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://picocms.org/', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
    const content = await page.content();
    request.data = JSON.stringify(content);
    await browser.close();
    db.collection('request')
        .add(request)
        .then(doc => {
            return res.json({
                message: `[success] ${doc.id} Generated`
            });
        })
        .catch(e => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: `[failed] No Request Was Saved _> ${e}`
            });
        });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `benchmark()` function is `async` and thus will return a Promise when called.

Therefore, you are trying to store a Promise here:

```js
        return change.after.ref.set(
            {
                results: benchmark()     // This is a promise
            },
            { merge: true }
        );
```

You want to store the resolved value from the Promise instead. You have to change your function to be `async` and then add an `await` in front of your `benchmark()` call. Then your data will become a "plain JavaScript object" and it can be serialized and stored.